# how to loop through every two items in div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my HTML  structure I want to check every two `productItem` `div` how can I check every two div
which JavaScript loop structure I need to use

```html
<div class="custompsps">
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>

</div>
<div class="custompsps">
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you _actually_ wanting to do this in javascript, ort are you trying to do something like apply some css style to every other row?

Comment: I want to check every two  productitem div actually I want to check spacing inside it I have other code but I don't know how to check every two div  only

Comment: Duplicate question: [how to ADD class in every to div using loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70090514/how-to-add-class-in-every-to-div-using-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all elements, and then loop over them,
This is an example if you want to add classes

```
let allProds = document.querySelectorAll(".ProductItem");
for(let i = 0; i< allProds.length; i+2){
    allProds[i].classList.add("everyOddItem");
}
```