# how to ADD class in every to div using loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my structure I want to add odd even class in every two divs so how can I achieve this structure using JavaScript loop i tried everything but i got nothing I am learning JavaScript loop so anyone please help me with this

```js
var i = 0;
$('.CollectionInner__Products .Grid__Cell .ProductItem').each(function(i) {
  var index = 0;
  if (index % 3 == 0) {
    $(this).addClass("odd");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="custompsps">
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>

</div>
<div class="custompsps">
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem">
  </div>

</div>
```

I want this structure:

```
i want this stucture
<div class="custompsps">
  <div class="ProductItem even">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem even">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem odd">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem odd">
  </div>

</div>
<div class="custompsps">
  <div class="ProductItem even">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem even">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem odd">
  </div>
  <div class="ProductItem odd">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: In your loop, you can use `if (i % 4 < 2)` to test if the current iteration is in the first two of a pair or the second two, and use that to decide which class to add.

Comment: Please show your best attempt and we'll help you fix it, we won't write the code for you.

Comment: var i=0;
$('.CollectionInner__Products  .Grid__Cell .ProductItem').each(function(i){
   var index = 0;
       if(index % 3 == 0) {
           $(this).addClass("odd");

        }
    
});

Comment: You're setting index to 0 every time, why would `index % 3` change? And why are you using `%3`? That tells you if the index is a multiple of 3, which has nothing to do with pairs.

Comment: You should be testing `i`, not `index`.

Comment: i got my answer thanks

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of adding even and odd is to the class? this could be an XY problem and might be solved with a CSS selector?

Comment: my logic is not working i need to think something different can wrap every two div into another div?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.CollectionInner__Products .Grid__Cell .ProductItem').each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).addClass(index & 2 ? "even" : "odd");
});
```

`&` is a [bitwise "and"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND). `index & 2` would be `0` for index 0 and 1, and `2` for index 2 and 3, alternating like this. `0` is falsy and non-`0` is truthy. (Your use of "even" and "odd" seem backwards, but I've followed your use.)

jQuery's [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) accepts a callback that can take both an index and an element argument.